# Did Postgresq vacuum execute when performing JDBC transaction?

Tags: postgresql

From PostgreSQL blog

> VACUUM reclaims storage occupied by dead tuples. In normal PostgreSQL operation, tuples that are deleted or obsoleted by an update are not physically removed from their table; they remain present until a VACUUM is done. Therefore it's necessary to do VACUUM periodically, especially on frequently-updated tables.

So, i had a performance optimization issue in java application with jdbc. So my question is did VACUUM executed on somewhere in JDBC transaction or need to set explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that quotation is saying the truth, it omits the fact that for a decade or so PostgreSQL has been having the [*autovacuum daemon*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) that does this job for you automatically.

So normally you don't have to concern yourself with that. Only on tables with very high write activity you have to tune autovacuum to be more aggressive, and you may need the occasional `VACUUM (FULL)` if you bulk-delete a large percentage of a table.

Performance issues are normally not connected with `VACUUM` (except that sequential scans take longer on bloated tables), so the connection is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You may control the running of VACUUM by do appropriate settings described in the section
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-FREEZE-MAX-AGE